# Is there an else for switches?

Tags: powershell

`switch` in PowerShell is like a less convoluted `if` `elseif` statement, but `else` doesn't work. Is there anything else I can do?

```
switch ("test") {
  "1" {"2"}
  "2" {"1"}
} else {"other"}
```

gives error

```
else : The term 'else' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:4 char:3
+ } else {"other"}
+   ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (else:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The else for switches is the `default` option:

```
switch ("test") {
  "1" {"2"}
  "2" {"1"}
  Default {"other"}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `default {...}`

For example:

https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-switch/

```
$num = Read-Host "Enter a number"
Switch ($num)
{
    1 {'Run Action 1'}
    2 {'Run Action 2'}
    3 {'Run Action 3'}
    default {'No Action'}
}
```